# Best method for generating low current (5 - 10 mA) -2.5 V supply

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, ldo

I am designing a digital system with various power supplies.  I need to generate positive and negative supplies for a component.  The voltages are +6.5 V and -2.5 V.  Both supplies will pull in the ~5 mA to 10 mA load currents.  I also will have a +2.5 voltage rail in the system that will have higher current in the couple of amps range.

I have an idea on how to do the +6.5 V with a buck converter, but the -2 V supply is giving me some trouble.  Most solutions I have been finding have a maximum negative voltage ≥ 3 V.

Some have suggested split supplies, but I don't see many in the ±2 V range. regulating to a "higher" negative supply like -5 V and then regulating to -2.5 V would be an option, but seems like it would add additional space and power to my design, which I would like to avoid.

I would gladly take any recommendations.

Cheers!

Comment: Best method, using which limitations? Which space and power limitations you then have? Any budget how much it can cost? Also, asking for suggestions what to buy is off-topic.

Comment: When I do [a parametric search at digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/pmic-voltage-regulators-dc-dc-switching-regulators/739?s=N4IgjCBcoEwKxyqAxlAZgQwDYGcCmANCAPZQDaIAzAOwCcALLRALpEAOALlCAMocBOASwB2AcxABfIgFoYSEKkgCAroRLkQtEMwm6gA), negative supply regulator "min output voltage" and "max output voltage" refer to the minimum and maximum MAGNITUDE respectively.  "maximum magnitude of output" being greater than 3V isn't a problem at all, as long as the "minimum magnitude of output" is less than 2.5V

Comment: So do your search again, with your definition of "minimum output voltage" and "maximum output voltage" flipped from what simple arithmetic says they should be.

Comment: Simple charge pump with one 555 can be a solution. Or look for buck-boost converter. Or isolated converter that can be connected in series with your 6.5v source.

Comment: Charge pump inverters cost about 2 dollars in small quantities. Add a linear regulator if needed.

Comment: I second @user1850479 but they often create rather low frequency ripple of 100 mV or more when loaded very lightly

Comment: Would you please specify what voltage you want to derive the -2.5 V supply from?  I posted an answer which assumes that there is a 5 V supply that I can use, but that may not necessarily be the case (and I may have therefore posted an answer that will not work for you.)  Please give me the chance to fix my answer, or at least better-prepare the next person willing to put significant work into helping you. Thank you for your consideration. Also, if you like my answer, please upvote it, and if it meets your needs, please accept it as well. Thanks again.

Comment: @Justme all good points those should have been in the original post and i will read the posting rules more carefully next time. I was mostly looking for small space solutions in the less than 5mmx5mm space. Price is not as much of a concern within reason any thing below~5 USD is okay.

Comment: I didn't specify which input voltage because at this point I'm still investigating which would be the most efficient. The trouble I have is both supplies are vey lightly loaded, most efficiency specs take a dive in this region as far as I can tell. Anyway thank you to all who asked for clarification or provided feedback I have some more to think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is a good case for the inverting mode of the classic MC34063 switching regulator.

Only 200mA saturation current is necessary, so a good, inexpensive inductor would be the $0.50 USD (at 1 qty) [Bourns RLB0914-331KL 1.25A Sat, 330 µH Unshielded Wirewound Inductor](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/bourns-inc/RLB0914-331KL/2352779) 740 mA, 760mOhm Max.

Here are the design parameters: 1.4 Vsat output sw, 0.5 Vf diode, 5 Vin, -2.5 Vout, 4.2 Vin(min), 0.050 Iout, 24KHz Fmin, 0.01 Vripple(pp)

[image: see previous paragraph, design parameters. This is a table with same parameters.]

And here's the worked-out design:  MC34063A design, Rsc=1.6 Ohm, L=330uH 200mA Sat. min., Ct=750pF, Cin=Cout=1000uF Low ESR, Vin=4.2v-6.0v, Vout=-2.5v, suggest the optional filter of 1uH + 100uF, R1=R2=4.7K Ohm

[image: See previous paragraph, worked-out design. This is the schematic.]

I did not verify the design (but I'm actually working on it -- could not get my LTSpice files for the MC34063 working, and I misplaced a chip that I had).  For the beginners happening on this information, a good Youtube video to watch is made by Dave of EEVblog: [**"EEVblog #110 - Let's Design a DC to DC Switchmode Converter"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGp82xhybs4) which I enjoy.

If you derive this -2.5 V supply from the 6.5 V supply which you mentioned that you will create, then the components need to change to the following:

- Ct = 620 pF
- Rsc = 1,870 mOhm
- L1 = 430 uH (still >= 200mA Sat)
- Cout >= 680 uF

Comment: MC34063 is an oldie but a goodie.  There are more modern devices that work well too.

Comment: Since I didn't specify the input voltage this answer is technically correct. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: @MiamiBatman - You're welcome. Did you see at the bottom that I also included values for your 6.5 volt supply? If you have another voltage, I will recalculate the values for you and give you updated information. Just ask.